# One user with multiple profiles

Tags: 7, commerce, users

I'm setting up a webshop were clients can have multiple profiles. For example a customer and supplier profile.

Whenever the user logges in, he gets a choice which profile he wants to sign in. Depending on which profile the user has selected, he gets to see different views.
Above this, the user should be able to change from profile within the site... Much like the [Masquerade](http://drupal.org/project/masquerade)-module, but in this case, it should be for all users.

I hope I make myself clear on this one...
Some advise on how to tackle this issue would be most welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Discussion about one user - multiple personas started and ended at drupal.org in 2007. I think your best bet is to use masquerade as a code example and implement it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with help of user roles

and [profile](http://drupal.org/project/profile2) module

> The module is aimed to provide a simple, but extensible solution providing a similar end user interface like the core profile module by
>   default.
>       Multiple profile types may be created via the UI (e.g. a general profile + a customer profile), whereas the module provides separated
>   permissions for those.

there is also a useful module which you can use

[Profile2 Registration Path](http://drupal.org/project/profile2_regpath)

> This module enables administrators to set unique registration paths
>   per Profile2 profile type

Comment: This doesn't allow users to switch accounts without logging out and back in though.

Comment: Answer is not relevant to question..